# how can i release a key after using action class with Sendkeys("15/16")

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am testing a drop-down where I am using an action class to select a season as "16/17" but as soon as I SendKeys it enter the correct value once and after loosing the control changes back to the defaulted season "18/19" ..please advise how should I release the key.
Note: arrow down key doesn't support here for this drop-down
using Firefox+Java+ webdriver

```
Actions builder1 = new Actions(driver);
WebElement mainelement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//gc-dropdown//div[* 
[contains(text(), 'Season')]]"));
Action SeriesOfActions6=builder1.moveToElement(mainelement).click()
.pause(2000).sendKeys("16/17",Keys.DOWN).click().build();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
SeriesOfActions6.perform();
```

dropdown for "18/19" element
`<div class="dropdown-display" ng-click="vm.onDropdownClick()" ng-class="{ 'clicked': vm.isDropdownOpen, 'dropdown-mobile' : vm.isMobile}">
<div class="animation ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="!vm.isFocussed"> 18/19 </div>`

dropdown for "16/17" element `<div class="dropdown-item ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in vm.values track by $index" ng-click="vm.onItemClick(item)" ng-class="{ 'selected': item.isSelected}" ng-disabled="item.isDisabled && item !== vm.selectedItem"> <span class="ng-binding">16/17</span>`

[screenshot of a page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziWLJ.png)

Comment: Update the question with the _Manual Steps_ you are trying to _Automate_ and the relevant _HTML_

Comment: Hi PF additional details:                                                                               
<div class="dropdown-display" ng-click="vm.onDropdownClick()" ng-class="{ 'clicked': vm.isDropdownOpen, 'dropdown-mobile' : vm.isMobile}">
<!-- ngIf: !vm.isFocussed -->
<div class="animation ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="!vm.isFocussed"> 18/19 </div>
<!-- end ngIf: !vm.isFocussed -->

Comment: dropdown for "16/17" element :::                                                                               <div class="dropdown-item ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in vm.values track by $index" ng-click="vm.onItemClick(item)" ng-class="{ 'selected': item.isSelected}" ng-disabled="item.isDisabled && item !== vm.selectedItem">
<span class="ng-binding">16/17</span>